# Angular directive "=" value binds to scope, but is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined the following directive inside my Angular app:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('almonds')
    .directive('security', ['$animate', 'AuthFactory', directive]);

    function directive($animate, AuthFactory) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                operation: "@",
                clearance: "@",
                project: "="
            },
            link: linkFunc
        };

        return directive;

        function linkFunc($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var block, childScope, previousElements;

            console.log($scope.project);

            if($scope.project) {
                var projectId = $scope.project.id;
            }

            var operation = $scope.operation;
            var clearance = $scope.clearance;


            if (projectId) {
                var value = AuthFactory.hasProjectAccess(projectId, clearance);
                console.log('PROJECT SECURITY:', projectId, clearance, value);
            } else {
                var value = AuthFactory.hasAccess(operation, clearance);
                console.log('ORG SECURITY:', operation, clearance, value);
            }
        }
    }
// Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
//
// function Controller($scope) {
//     var vm = this;
//
//     activate();
//
//     function activate() {
//
//     }
// }
})();
```

It is to be used as an element that receives either an `operation` or `project` value as well as a `clearance` value, which will then be used whether said element will render (I omitted that part but it's functionality is basically the same as `ng-if`).

Here's an example of it in use:

```
<span security project="vm.project" clearance="admin">
    <a role="button" ng-click="vm.confirmDeletion();"><span class="melon-icon-md melon-icon-trash"></span></a>
</span>
```

What's happening though, is that even though `vm.project` is indeed defined, that `console.log($scope.project);` yields `undefined`. Interestingly, if I simply `console.log($scope);` it *will* contain a `project` property with the information I need. What am I doing wrong?

I actually only need the project's `id` value, so I can either pass in the entire `project` object and access its `id` within the directive, or somehow pass the `id` number alone.

Comment: `<a role="button"` … what is wrong with `<button`?

Comment: I'm using `ui-sref`, not on that particular link but they're all the same for the sake of consistency.

Comment: please provide us plunker or jsfiddle to see the cause

Comment: FYI, `$scope, $element, $attr` should be `scope, element, attrs` : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2716-when-to-use-scope-vs-scope-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your directive's link function starts executing, vm.project is undefined at that point. Set a watch on $scope.project.

Inside Directive:

```
$scope.$watch('project', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, `vm.project` is indeed the result of an asynchronous call within the parent controller, so this must be the case.

Comment: It's classical race issue that everyone faced at least once when doing something in Angular, $watch is fine but since value is not changing make it together with watch destroyer `var watchDestroy - $scope.$watch('project, function(){ if(something) { //do stuff and run watchDestroy()} })`

Comment: Yes. Watch is useless once vm.project gets set.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way of doing this though? Do I really need a `$watch` every time I must pass an object asynchronously?

Comment: I can't think of any other way of doing this. I think, you need a $watch. As @maurycy said, you can destroy watch once the variable gets initialised. I believe, it is efficient way to do this.

Comment: Only when it requires an action after passing the object, but you could do `ng-if="vm.project"` that way the directive would be rendered only when object exists

Comment: I prefer $watch over ng-if because it would be easier for others to reuse the directive. If I would be reusing the directive written by someone else I would not expect to use ng-if in the directive.